# regex to find files not starting from a particular string with list.files()

Tags: regex, r, regex-negation

I'm trying to list files in a folder which don't start with a particular string. I tried using the below regex but was not successful. I want to list the files which don't start with "SH". This gives me a syntax error:

```
myFiles = list.files(pattern = "^((?!SH).)*\\.csv")
```

Comment: Try `myFiles = list.files(pattern = "^(?!SH).*\\.csv", perl=T)`.

Comment: Thank for the reply. However R doesn't seem to recognise perl=T. Do I need to use a library for this?

Comment: If `perl=T` is not accepted, try `"^[^S].*\\.csv|^.[^H].*\\.csv|^.\\.csv"`. Or a more compact `^(.|[^S].*|.[^H].*)\\.csv`.

Comment: Thanks alot stribizhev. This one worked!

Comment: I added my answer. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I'm new to R and regular expressions. @stribizhev in your answer, your are checking a single character (.) at the beginning (^). The expression will return the strings which does not begin with S or (|) H. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is a kind of a workaround for regex engines that do not support look-arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to work around the lack of `perl=T` support in `list.files()`:

```
^(.|[^S].*|.[^H].*)\\.csv
```

Here is [a demo of how this regex work](https://regex101.com/r/kD6yR5/1)

This regex allows any 1-character filenames, or 2-character filenames with no `SH` at the beginning and any other filenames.

So, use

```
myFiles = list.files(pattern = "^(.|[^S].*|.[^H].*)\\.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `grep`:

```
grep("^((?!SH).)*\\.csv", list.files(), perl=T, value=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

While `list.files` allows a regex pattern for matching, it does not (appear) to have the full flexibility of `grep` or `gsub` or `gregexp` as described in `help('regex')`, specifically it does not have a `perl` argument to pass through along with the pattern.

However, the following should do the trick (assuming you are wanting all files not starting with SH, but ending with `.csv`.

```
list.files(pattern = '^[^SH].+\\.csv$')
```

Answer (score 0):

This function list all files **not** started with "SH" and ended with ".csv"

`list.files()[!grepl("^SH.*\\.csv$",list.files())]`

or if you want to ignore cases, use `ignore.case=T`:

`list.files()[!grepl("^SH.*\\.csv$",list.files(),ignore.case=T)]`

Comment: Thanks nurandi. However the expression results in all the files and folders (doesn't filter the csv files) not starting with SH.

Comment: @stribizhev answer is cool. But, it also lists folder. Add `myFiles = myFiles[!file.info(myFiles)$isdir]` to exclude folder